# Real tracking app for iPhone?

Tags: iphone, applications, gps, geolocation

Is there an app that can tell me someone else's exact or general location by entering their phone number, no matter if they give permission or not? (Preferably not.) Or is there some other device, software, etc. that I can purchase? Something that is real and not just for entertainment purposes.

Comment: "If they must give permission or not (preferably not)" sounds SO VERY MUCH like illegal activities. Can you explain the comment to make this much more palatable for other readers?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Not on the App Store. Something like this is a likely violation of privacy laws as well. There's no way Apple would allow it.

Answer (score 1):

The only functionality that you'll find for a non-jailbroken iPhone is the Mobile Me [Find My iPhone](http://www.apple.com/mobileme/features/find-my-iphone.html) service.  For Jailbroken iPhones there's [Navimote](http://www.navizon.com/products_navimote.asp), [Undercover Mobile](http://www.orbicule.com/undercover/iphone/index.html), and quite a few others.